# Can't show logout after successfully logging in without refresh in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

After successfully logging in, the logout button is not visible in the header section but when I refresh the page it becomes visible and after that I can remove the cookies. How can I make it work without refreshing the page? It's a single page application in AngularJS.

index.html

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="top-bar-link top-bar-link-left">
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call us: 090 456 7823</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> 30 Days Exchange Policy</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="top-bar-link top-bar-link-right dot">                    
            <li><a href="#checkout" >Checkout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#compare">Compare</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sign_up" ng-show="!isauthentication">Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#login" ng-show="!isauthentication">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="" ng-show="isauthentication" ng-click="logout()" >Logout</a></li>                      
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

logincontroller.js

```javascript
app.controller('loginController', [
    '$scope',
    '$location',
    'datafactory',
    '$cookieStore',
    function($scope, $location, datafactory, $cookieStore) {
        var keycookie;
        $scope.status;
        $scope.customers;

        $scope.isauthentication = false;
        init();
        function init() {
            if ($cookieStore.get('keycookie') != null) {

                $scope.isauthentication = true;

                console.log("print");
            } else {

                $scope.isauthentication = false;

                console.log("falseprint");
            }

        }

        $scope.login = function() {
            datafactory.postLogin($scope.email, $scope.password).then(
                    function(response) {
                        if (response.data.success == true) {

                            $cookieStore.put('keycookie',response.data.key);
                            $cookieStore.put('emailcookie',$scope.email);
                            var keycookie = $cookieStore.get('keycookie');
                            console.log(keycookie);
                            var emailcookie = $cookieStore.get('emailcookie');
                            console.log(emailcookie);
                            init();
                            console.log("login success");

                            $location.path("/home");

                        }
                    }, function(error) {
                        window.location.href = "#/login";
                    });
        }
        $scope.logout = function() {

            if ($cookieStore.get('keycookie') != null) {
                $cookieStore.remove('keycookie');
                init();
            }
            init();
        }
    } ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
 function init() {
 $timeout(function() {
     if ($cookieStore.get('keycookie') != null) {

         $scope.isauthentication = true;

         console.log("print");
     } else {

         $scope.isauthentication = false;

         console.log("falseprint");
     }
 });
}
```

This will wait for any existing digest cycle to complete and then trigger a new so that current scope is updated with latest values.

Also try this:

```
$timeout(function() {
     $location.path("/home");
 });
```

Comment: i add this in my code but its not working, and again i have to refresh the page for show 'logout';

Comment: are you getting redirected to /login url

Comment: after login success you are redirected to  /home  url

Comment: sorry i mean i m successfully redirected on /home page, and yes if i will use location.reload(); then it will show logout button,but its not a proper way.

Comment: have you tried this $timeout(function() {
     $location.path("/home");
 });